# UWP sideload installer and distribution via web with trusted certificate

Tags: uwp, windows-store-apps, windows-store, appx

I'm looking for a way how I can distribute my app without windows store?

Here's new nice LOB approach to load via MS App Installer
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appinstaller/2017/09/26/uwp-app-installs-from-web-via-app-installer/comment-page-1/#comment-12545

but an issue here is certification, a user should install my dev certificate to his PC and it is not unacceptable for me

And I have found 2 solutions:

1) Create old fashion installer with background installation of my dev certificate but the implementation of this approach will take a long time.

2) I can use fiddler and get my appx bundle from the Windows Store and it is what I need.

And yes, my app is in the Windows Store and I want to give more ways to download my app via the web!

And I have a logic question, is there a convenient way to get my appx signed for the windows store? Or the certificate what will be accepted by SmartScreen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is there a convenient way to get my appx signed for the windows store? Or the certificate what will be accepted by SmartScreen?

For this scenario, you could directly upload your self-signed appx package as well as the certificate file to hosted web server.

Since your app is public in Windows Store, I guess it's not an LOB app. If so, you do not have to buy the certificate from CA though it's recommended to do that. Because certificate from CA could provide more security and longer expiration time. For example, it can protect your code integrity and users will have security warning or fail to download if the hash used to sign doesn't match the hash used to download your app. It just depends on your requirement.

SmartScreen is a module within App Installer to help users avoid downloading junk or viruses files. It's used to check and detect the safety of your package. You could also use your self-signed certificate though Trusted CA certificate could be better.

Answer (score 0):

For LOB, you can use the Active Directory to deploy the certificates. 
Or, You can purchase the digital certificate from certificate authorities and use it to sign your appx package.
Using of 'self-signed certificate' package is totally out of scope for public deploying.

Comment: You can purchase the digital certificate from certificate authorities and use it to sign your appx package - And this certificate will be approved by SmartScreen?